# How to install/use JUnit?

Tags: java

I have installed JUnit on my Ubuntu 11.04

```
sudo apt-get install junit
```

Then created a test file like:

```
import org.junit.*;

public class TestBasicLinkedList {
  @Test public void testCanAdd(String[] args) {
    BasicLinkedList<Integer> list = new BasicLinkedList();
    list.add(new BasicListNode<Integer>(1));
    assertTrue(list.size() == 1);
    assertTrue(list.getFirst().getElement().equals(1));
  }
}
```

Then tried running in terminal

```
java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore TestBasicLinkedList.java
```

Got:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/runner/JUnitCore
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.runner.JUnitCore
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: org.junit.runner.JUnitCore. Program will exit.
```

How do I use JUnit? Is there a better shorter way of using it than the long command `java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore TestBasicLinkedList.java`? Perhaps something like `junit *.Tests.java` maybe?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In general, JUnit (just like any Java library) needs to be on your classpath.  I don't know where exactly Ubuntu stores junitX.jar, but you probably want something like this:

```
java -cp .:/usr/share/java/junit4-4.10.jar TestBasicLinkedList
```

You'll need to compile `TestBasicLinkedList` first.

Comment: `/usr/share/java/junit.jar` links to the latest junit3 version, while `/usr/share/java/junit4.jar` links to the latest junit4 version.

Answer (score 13):

To get you up and running, this is a basic test case:

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class TestBasicLinkedList extends TestCase {
  public void testTrue() {
    assertTrue(true);
  }
}
```

The test class should extend TestCase, and test methods should start with "test", accept no arguments and return void.

To compile:

```
javac -cp /usr/share/java/junit4.jar TestBasicLinkedList.java
```

To run:

```
java -cp /usr/share/java/junit4.jar:. org.junit.runner.JUnitCore TestBasicLinkedList
```

This is for JUnit 4; JUnit 3 uses different classes for executing tests (try junit.textui.TestRunner).

Comment: Thanks .. `java -cp /usr/share/java/junit.jar:. junit.textui.TestRunner TestBasicLinkedList` works for JUnit3. This was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install junit4
```

- `/usr/share/java/junit4.jar` is a symlink to the latest junit4
  version.
- `/usr/share/java/junit.jar` is a symlink to the latest junit3
  version.

**If your application requires that you to set `$JUNIT_HOME`:**

```
mkdir ~/junit
ln -s /usr/share/java/junit4.jar ~/junit
ln -s /usr/share/java/hamcrest-core.jar ~/junit
export JUNIT_HOME=~/junit
```

**If your application requires it to have it in your `$CLASSPATH`:**

Just copy it into one of your application's classpath directories.